# Android: Possible to download imageview to phone or set an imageview as background?

Tags: android, image, download, background-image, imageview

I have an app that contains a picture gallery when one of the items in the gallery is pressed, the item clicked views as an imageview fullscreen.  What I am then trying to do is allow the user to select whether to download the imageview to the phone or set it as a background...is this possible? How would I go about this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use WallpaperManager [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html#setStream(java.io.InputStream)) to the the system wallpaper.

Answer (score 0):

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resourcId);
    WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager =     WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    try {
        myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```